# php echo href from mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql, href

Ok, so I have the php echo working and pulling specific url's from the mysql database but this string that I got from an example is adding in single quotes to my href. So instead of being localhost/newdesign/about.php it is localhost/newdesign/'about.php'.

here is the code:

```
<p>
<?php 
  echo '<a href="\'' . $row['url'] . '\'" style="color: #137e80" (\''.$row['url'].'\');return false;">' . $row['url'] . '</a>'; 
?>
</p>
```

Thank You

Comment: You're adding the single quotes yourself in that string.

Comment: Because you're echoing `\'`

Comment: What is that `return false;` doing in there? Is there a missing `onclick=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the 2nd apostrophe.

```
"' . $row['url'] . '"
```

Comment: No need for the backslash, either

Comment: wait so it would look like this : <p><?php echo '<a href=" . $row['url'] . " style="color: #137e80" (.$row['url'].);return false;">' . $row['url'] . '</a>'; ?></p><!--code ends here--> I tried but i get a php error saying it is expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Look at your row string compared to mine. Now you're missing apostrophe's, there needs to be at least 1 to escape the interpreter. Alternatively, you can use commas instead of periods as well.

Comment: ok that helped me out more but still not 100%. newcdoe:<p><?php echo '<a href="' . $row['url'] . '" style="color: #137e80" ('.$row['url'].');return false;">' . $row['url'] . '</a>'; ?></p><!--code ends here--> Now I do not get any errors but my about.php is still like this: 'about.php'. I know this is probably a easy fix but I am not very good at php just yet.

Comment: What's wrong with that? isn't that the value that's int he row?

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler if you use `<?php echo` only around the variables, not the literal HTML parts as well. It also looks like part of the `onclick` got lost when you were copying to SO.

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $row['url'] ?>" style="color: #137d80" onclick="somefunction('<?php echo $row['url'] ?>'); return false;"><?php echo $row['url'] ?></a></p>
```

Comment: so that onclick="somefunction" is already being filled in with the php echo correct? I do not need to add a script and define somefunction()?

Comment: You do. I assumed it was already there, you just messed up when you were copying to SO. Of course, use the name of your actual function.

Comment: I'm sorry, this was an example code I took and started to make it work for my site. I tried your code but I still get the 2 single quotes '' around my about.php. It looks like this: 'about.php' but it should be like this: about.php

Comment: The only way that could happen is if the quotes are in `$row['url']`.